# How to cut one word after match in file directory

Tags: regex, grep

In my repository there are folders called "branches" and that's the only thing I know. I need to extract everything until match "branches" and one more folder after branches. So I have this output

> NonSCAComponents/BkpTimingScripts/SRC/branches/black/
>   NonSCAComponents/BkpTimingScripts/SRC/branches/black/scripts/
>   NonSCAComponents/BkpTimingScripts/SRC/branches/black/scripts/Backplane/
>   NonSCAComponents/BkpTimingScripts/SRC/branches/black/scripts/ssh/
>   NonSCAComponents/BkpTimingScripts/SRC/branches/white/

And I want only this

> NonSCAComponents/BkpTimingScripts/SRC/branches/black/
>   NonSCAComponents/BkpTimingScripts/SRC/branches/white/

I tried using egrep/grep to catch the branches folder and everything before it. Also sort -u to eliminate repeats.

```
egrep -io "^.*branches/.*/" | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '^.*/branches/[^/]+/' file | sort -u
```

```
NonSCAComponents/BkpTimingScripts/SRC/branches/black/
NonSCAComponents/BkpTimingScripts/SRC/branches/white/
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `.*/branches/`: Match everything followed by `/branches/`
- `[^/]+`: Match 1 or more of non-slash characters
- `/`: Match literal `/`